# Why the class is not taking the argument?

Tags: python

```
class Dog(object):
    def __int__(self,name, age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age

    def speak(self):
        print("hi i am", self.name, 'and I am', self.age, 'years old')

tim = Dog ('Tim', 55 )
fred = Dog ('Fred', 3)
tim.speak()
fred.speak()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not take the argument"? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Typo: Should be `init`?

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelled `__init__`

Here's the fixed code:

```py
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self,name, age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age

    def speak(self):
        print("hi i am", self.name, 'and I am', self.age, 'years old')

tim = Dog ('Tim', 55 )
fred = Dog ('Fred', 3)
tim.speak()
fred.speak()
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of Dog(object)

replace `__int__` with `__init__`

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def speak(self):
        print("hi I am {}, {} years old".format(self.name,self.age))

tim = Dog("Tim", 55 )
fred = Dog("Fred", 3)
tim.speak()
fred.speak()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your class definition is wrong. Try with:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
```